# How to read specific date and time for specific values in csv file using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, time

Here I have a dataset with date ,time and one inputs. Here I want to read date and time together for specific values. Here I want to keep the length of csv file as same without changing.

Here 5 values contain time convert 00:00:00.

Here I used some code but it gave me with 0 days. First I convert that specific time into `00:00:00`

```
data['date_time']= pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'],
                        format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)

data['duration'] = np.where(data['X3'].eq(5), np.timedelta64(0), pd.to_timedelta(data['date_time']))


print(data['duration'])


def f(x):
ts = x.total_seconds()
hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
return ('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)) 

data['duration'] = data['duration'].apply(f)
```

output :

```html
5      00:00:00
11     00:00:00
18     00:00:00
25     00:00:00
30     00:00:00
37     00:00:00
43     00:00:00
46     00:00:00
54     00:00:00
60     00:00:00
65     00:00:00
70     00:00:00
80     00:00:00
82     00:00:00
89     00:00:00
95     00:00:00
99     00:00:00
104    00:00:00
111    00:00:00
114    00:00:00
121    00:00:00
```

But what I expected output  is:

```html
    datetime               x3
10/3/2018 6:15:00      7
10/3/2018 00:00:00      5
10/3/2018 7:45:00      7
10/3/2018 9:00:00      7
10/3/2018 9:25:00      7
10/3/2018 00:00:00      5
10/3/2018 11:00:00     7
10/3/2018 11:30:00     7
10/3/2018 13:30:00     7
10/3/2018 00:00:00     5
10/3/2018 15:00:00     7
10/3/2018 15:25:00     7
10/3/2018 16:25:00     7
10/3/2018 00:00:00     5
10/3/2018 19:00:00     7
10/3/2018 19:30:00     7
```

Means replace time with 00:00:00

```html
date time x3               T                   x3
10/3/2018 6:15:00 7 10/3/2018 6:15:00  7
10/3/2018 6:45:00 5 10/3/2018 0:00:00  5
10/3/2018 7:45:00 7 10/3/2018 7:45:00  7
10/3/2018 9:00:00 7 10/3/2018 9:00:00         7
10/3/2018 9:25:00 7 10/3/2018 9:25:00  7
10/3/2018 9:30:00 5 10/3/2018 0:00:00  5
```

Subset of my csv:

```html
date              time x3
10/3/2018 6:15:00  7
10/3/2018 6:45:00  5
10/3/2018 7:45:00  7
10/3/2018 9:00:00         7 
10/3/2018 9:25:00    7
10/3/2018 9:30:00         5
10/3/2018 11:00:00 7
10/3/2018 11:30:00 7
10/3/2018 13:30:00 7
10/3/2018 13:50:00 5
10/3/2018 15:00:00 7
10/3/2018 15:25:00 7
10/3/2018 16:25:00 7
10/3/2018 18:00:00 5
10/3/2018 19:00:00 7
10/3/2018 19:30:00 7
10/3/2018 20:00:00 7
10/3/2018 22:05:00 7
10/3/2018 22:15:00 5
10/3/2018 23:40:00 7
10/4/2018 6:58:00         5
10/4/2018 13:00:00 7
10/4/2018 16:00:00 7
10/4/2018 17:00:00 7
10/4/2018 18:00:00 7
10/5/2018 7:00:00         7
10/5/2018 8:00:00   7
10/5/2018 9:00:00         7
```

[My csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit#gid=1512153575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove times in `date_time` column only for rows with `data['x3'].eq(5)` with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) by days:

```
data['date_time']= pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'],
                        format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)

mask = data['x3'].eq(5)
data['date_time'] = data['date_time'].mask(mask, data['date_time'].dt.floor('d'))
```

---

```
print (data)
         date      time  x3           date_time
0   10/3/2018   6:15:00   7 2018-03-10 06:15:00
1   10/3/2018   6:45:00   5 2018-03-10 00:00:00
2   10/3/2018   7:45:00   7 2018-03-10 07:45:00
3   10/3/2018   9:00:00   7 2018-03-10 09:00:00
4   10/3/2018   9:25:00   7 2018-03-10 09:25:00
5   10/3/2018   9:30:00   5 2018-03-10 00:00:00
6   10/3/2018  11:00:00   7 2018-03-10 11:00:00
7   10/3/2018  11:30:00   7 2018-03-10 11:30:00
8   10/3/2018  13:30:00   7 2018-03-10 13:30:00
9   10/3/2018  13:50:00   5 2018-03-10 00:00:00
10  10/3/2018  15:00:00   7 2018-03-10 15:00:00
11  10/3/2018  15:25:00   7 2018-03-10 15:25:00
12  10/3/2018  16:25:00   7 2018-03-10 16:25:00
13  10/3/2018  18:00:00   5 2018-03-10 00:00:00
14  10/3/2018  19:00:00   7 2018-03-10 19:00:00
15  10/3/2018  19:30:00   7 2018-03-10 19:30:00
16  10/3/2018  20:00:00   7 2018-03-10 20:00:00
17  10/3/2018  22:05:00   7 2018-03-10 22:05:00
18  10/3/2018  22:15:00   5 2018-03-10 00:00:00
19  10/3/2018  23:40:00   7 2018-03-10 23:40:00
20  10/4/2018   6:58:00   5 2018-04-10 00:00:00
21  10/4/2018  13:00:00   7 2018-04-10 13:00:00
22  10/4/2018  16:00:00   7 2018-04-10 16:00:00
23  10/4/2018  17:00:00   7 2018-04-10 17:00:00
24  10/4/2018  18:00:00   7 2018-04-10 18:00:00
25  10/5/2018   7:00:00   7 2018-05-10 07:00:00
26  10/5/2018   8:00:00   7 2018-05-10 08:00:00
27  10/5/2018   9:00:00   7 2018-05-10 09:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But the output came " 10/3/2018 6:45:00  5, 10/3/2018 9:30:00         5 "  Like this. But I want to convert this time "00:00:00" keeping the date format as like this.

Comment: @team - So you need remove times in next step? Check solution, but there are no `00:00:00`, because not displayed in pandas

Comment: @ jezrael No no I want time. Hay I edited my expected output. Can you may look at that output?

Comment: @team - Can you test now?

Comment: @ jezrael  same as earlier output friend. It is not displayed as what I expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `duration` from your code for `T`. it should be

```
T = data.loc[data['duration'] == match_time, ['date','duration','x3']]
```

When you put `duration` in there, what you are asking Pandas is to get the column `duration` when `data['duration'] == match_time`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But the output came " 10/3/2018 6:45:00 5, 10/3/2018 9:30:00 5 " Like this. But I want to convert this time "00:00:00" keeping the date format as like this

Comment: Not worked. Here I edited my expected output . Can you may look at it?